# How do I find out what RPMs make up a "yum group install"?

Tags: linux, redhat, rpm, rhel5

I am trying to install the Gnome Desktop Environment on a RHEL 5 system.
I am NOT connected to the internet and do NOT have any local repo or the install disks.

Under normal circumstances, where a repo is available, I understand the easiest way to do this would be to:

```
# yum groupinstall "GNOME Desktop Environment"
```

But since I don't have access to a repo, I will need to download all the individual RPMs that make up this groupinstall.

So my question is, how do I find out what RPMs get installed with the "GNOME Desktop Environment" groupinstall so I know what RPMs I need to download?

**EDIT: So I can download the entire distro on a DVD and use the DVD as a repo, but let's say I don't have a CD/DVD drive and need to download the RPMs individually.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run `yum groupinfo "GNOME Desktop Environment"`, which on an EL5 system, will display:

```
Group: GNOME Desktop Environment
 Description: GNOME is a powerful, graphical user interface which includes a panel, desktop, system icons, and a graphical file manager.
 Mandatory Packages:
   control-center
   gnome-applets
   gnome-panel
   gnome-session
   gnome-terminal
   metacity
   nautilus
   yelp
 Default Packages:
   NetworkManager-gnome
   alacarte
   at-spi
   desktop-printing
   dvd+rw-tools
   eog
   esc
   evince
   file-roller
   gedit
   gimp-print-utils
   gnome-audio
   gnome-backgrounds
   gnome-mag
   gnome-media
   gnome-netstatus
   gnome-pilot
   gnome-power-manager
   gnome-screensaver
   gnome-system-monitor
   gnome-themes
   gnome-user-docs
   gnome-user-share
   gnome-utils
   gnome-vfs2-smb
   gnome-volume-manager
   gok
   gtk2-engines
   gtkhtml3
   im-chooser
   nautilus-cd-burner
   nautilus-open-terminal
   nautilus-sendto
   notification-daemon
   orca
   sabayon-apply
   vino
 Optional Packages:
   compiz
   dasher
   gconf-editor
   gnome-bluetooth
   gnome-keyring-manager
   gnome-pilot-conduits
   hal-gnome
   pinentry-gtk
```